# Rest design principles

Tags: rest, wadl, url-design

Is the following a good rest design practice for listing all the subscriptions of a customer:

[BaseUrl]/subscriptions/[accountid]/payTV 
[BaseUrl]/subscriptions/[accountid]/paywall
etc...

ORshould it rather be:

[BaseUrl]/subscriptions/payTV?[accountID]
[BaseUrl]/subscriptions/paywall?[accountID]
etc...

OR something else?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that accountid is the unique id for a customer and payTV/paywall are subscription types, I would choose something like the following:

```
[BaseUrl]/customers/[accountid]/subscriptions?type=payTV
[BaseUrl]/customers/[accountid]/subscriptions?type=paywall
```

Comment: Further to this, if the only thing you can filter a subscription on is `type`, you can just leave off the query string and use `/customers/[accountid]/subscriptions/paywall`